# Linear combinations in a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: vector-spaces

This question is related to [Prove that a subspace of dimension $n$ of a vector space of dimension $n$ is the whole space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165726/prove-that-a-subspace-of-dimension-n-of-a-vector-space-of-dimension-n-is-the)

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\{v_i\}\;( i \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}\; v_i \in S)$ a set of  $n$ lienarly independent vectors such that $\forall v \in S $ there exists $n$ real numbers $\{a_i\}$ not all null such that   $\sum_i{a_iv_i}=v$  (i.e.   $\{v_i\}$ is a basis for $S$).

My question is:

Show that **for all** $\{b_i\}\;( b_i \in \mathbb{R}\;,  i \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\})$  the linear combination:
$$
\sum_i{b_iv_i}=u 
$$
is an element of $S$.

Comment: How picky of a proof do you want? A subspace $S$ is closed under vector addition and under scalar multiplication.... :) If you want more detail, induction on the number of summands is easy.

Comment: It seems to me that the question is not so trivial, because the existence of a set $\{a_i\}$ for all vectors in $S$ don't immediately means that all possible $n$-ples  of real numbers are one of the $\{a_i\}$.
But maybe that i'm complicating something that is very simple.

Comment: @user86418: May be that the word ''subspace''in the title is misleading. And I've some trouble in express the question in clear english. I suppose that the question can be expressed as: if every element of $S$ is a linear combination of $\{v_i\}$, then $S$ is necessarily a vector space?

Comment: The answer to your last question is certainly "no"; take $S$ to be an arbitrary subset of the span of the $\{v_{i}\}$. :) But the set of _all_ linear combinations from some set _is_ a subspace. Incidentally, I added a comment to your original question that may help with implementing Mark Joshi's strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is false. Consider
$$
S=\{1\}
$$
in $\mathbb{R}^1$. Then the assumption holds for $S$: the single vector in $S$ can be written as a linear combination of elements in $S$, but of course it's not a subspace.

If you start with the hypothesis that $S$ is a subspace, then the assumption about every vector in $S$ being a nontrivial linear combination of the vectors $v_i$ cannot be fulfilled for the zero vector.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to show that $S$ is a subspace of $R^n$.